# Come posso esprimere "to pull strings to get / to make someone to get a job, a position" in italiano?

Tags: word-choice, translation, phrase-request, colloquial

Colloquialmente, in castigliano usiamo "enchufarse" e in catalano "endollar-se" (la traduzione letterale di questi verbi sarebbe più o meno "attaccarsi la spina") per esprimere l'idea che in inglese si direbbe "to pull strings to get a job, a position". Per esempio, questa frase in spagnolo

> Se ha enchufado en el ayuntamiento

si potrebbe tradurre in inglese come

> He / She / (They) has (have) pulled strings to get a job in the city council.

Utilizziamo anche "enchufar a alguien" in castigliano e "endollar algú" in catalano (anche colloquialmente) per dire quello che in inglese sarebbe "to pull strings to hire someone, to make someone to get a position": "alguien" e "algú" si possono tradurre come "qualcuno", sarebbe come se questa persona avesse una spina elettrica e la traduzione letterale sarebbe approssimativamente "attaccare la spina" di questa persona. Per esempio, in castigliano possiamo dire

> Su amigo lo ha enchufado en el ayuntamiento

e in inglese sarebbe

> His friend has pulled strings to get him a job in the city council.

In inglese, ["pull strings"](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pull_strings) significa

> sfruttare la propria influenza e i propri contatti per ottenere un vantaggio ufficiosamente o ingiustamente.

"Enchufarse" e "endollar-se" significano

> riuscire a ottenere un posto di lavoro, una certa carica, una promozione, ecc. sfruttando la propria influenza e i propri contatti ufficiosamente o ingiustamente.

Il senso di "enchufar a alguien" e "endollar algú" è

> fare che qualcuno ottenga un posto di lavoro, una certa carica, una promozione, ecc. sfruttando la propria influenza e i propri contatti ufficiosamente o ingiustamente.

Esiste qualche modo colloquiale o informale per esprimere questo in italiano? In generale, come potrei tradurre questo tipo di espressioni?

Comment: Non so alcunché di Spagnolo, Catalano e Castigliano. Però se intendi *pull the strings* (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-the-strings), un modo di dire equivalente è *tirare le fila*, ma mi pare che non corrisponda a quello che intendi tu. Quindi per me la domanda non è chiara.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Non è "pull the strings", è "pull strings". Bene: forse dovrei aggiungere una spiegazione sul significato di "pull strings". Castigliano e spagnolo sono la stessa lingua. Diciamo che la lingua esisteva prima dell'esistenza della Spagna e si parlava nel regno di Castiglia (insieme con altre lingue).

Comment: Io ho trovato questi, ma nessuno corrisponde: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+strings
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pull-strings
https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pull+strings
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pull

Comment: Menziono, come possibile spunto, che sul Ragazzini inglese-italiano “to pull (a few) strings” viene reso con “manovrare; brigare; darsi da fare; lavorare nell'ombra”.

Comment: Grazie, @DaG. Sul chat ho linkato alcune cose che ho appena trovato sul Treccani, ma veramente non sono sicura di nulla.

Comment: Non lo aggiungo come risposta @Charo, ma hai mai sentito l'espressione "fare dei magheggi"? Molto colloquiale come espressione e probabilmente d'origine romana, vedi se si allinea con ciò che cerchi.

Comment: No, @Easymode44: non conosco questa espressione.

Comment: minor: AFAIK "enchufarse" only has this meaning in Spain (ref: https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=enchufar). I have never heard it in Latin America.

Answer (score 2):

In italiano si potrebbe tradurre come ["raccomandare"](https://www.garzantilinguistica.it/ricerca/?q=raccomandare), significato 2, oppure sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI15/00227.jpg):

> interporre i propri buoni uffici o esercitare pressioni, in partic. nell’assegnazione di un posto di lavoro, nel superamento di esami scolastici, nell’avanzamento di una pratica burocratica o in altre circostanze e situazioni della vita associata (e può apparire moralmente riprovevole come favoriti­smo o come prevaricazione e ingiustizia nei con­fronti di chi è veramente meritevole).

Esempi:

> Ha vinto il concorso grazie alle raccomandazioni di suo zio, che è professore nello stesso dipartimento.
>
> Quello è un raccomandato, sicuramente assegneranno l'incarico a lui.

Da notare che il verbo "raccomandare" non sempre ha il significato peggiorativo di "enchufar"; di solito il contesto dovrebbe chiarire l'intenzione.

Questi termini con questo significato possono usarsi e si usano spesso in contesti informali e colloquiali, ma non sono infrequenti anche in registri leggermente più formali (per esempio, in un giornale o notiziario televisivo).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106120/discussion-on-answer-by-persson-come-posso-esprimere-to-pull-strings-to-get-t).