# Significato di "raccomandato" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Nichel* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Dopo qualche settimana mi accorsi che non ero piú un senza nome: ero un Dott. Levi che non doveva essere chiamato Levi, né alla seconda né alla terza persona, per buona creanza, per non far nascere imbrogli. Nell’atmosfera pettegola e tollerante delle Cave, lo sfasamento fra la mia indeterminata condizione di fuoricasta e la mia visibile mitezza di costumi saltava agli occhi, e, mi confessò Alida, veniva lungamente commentata e variamente interpretata: dall’agente dell'Ovra al **raccomandato** d'alto livello.

Le Cave menzionate nel brano fanno riferimento a una miniera in cui Levi stava lavorando da poco tempo come addetto a un laboratorio.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire "raccomandato" in questo passaggio. Il significato sarebbe quello spiegato in [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/12673)?

Ricercando alla voce "raccomandato" di parecchi dizionari, è l'unica accezione che mi sembra possa avere senso nel contesto del testo, ma non sono sicura che il significato sia questo.

Comment: @egreg:  Sì, il significato 1 del Treccani è appunto quello a cui si riferisce la risposta che ho linkato. Tuttavia, non credo che questo "raccomandato" fosse una persona dell'OVRA, ma probabilmente qualcuno che occupava qualche carica nella miniera. Perlomeno è così come io intendo il testo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il significato di "raccomandato" è indubbiamente quello che hai trovato e dell'accezione 1 del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/raccomandato/) come indicano i commenti.
Hai anche ragione secondo me nel ritenere che non si tratti necessariamente di una persona dell'OVRA.

L'autore usa l'espressione "il" raccomandato per rimarcare il fatto che è diciamo una sorta di figura di prammatica, presenza "naturale" in tutti i luoghi di lavoro, incluso il suo. Una specie di "figura professionale", come dire "l'ingegnere" o "il geometra".

Comment: Ho aggiunto il link al Treccani perché i commenti, in teoria, possono essere cancellati in qualsiasi momento: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237978/.

Comment: Per maggiore comprensione, consideriamo che nel 1941, quando Primo Levi lavorò a Balangero (esperienza di cui parla in Nichel), era come dice lui un «fuoricasta», nel senso che lavorava “clandestinamente” (era ebreo e per via delle leggi razziali non avrebbe potuto lavorare). Con quella frase si intende che tutti quelli [dal … al] che erano lì non per motivi professionali non potevano che essere stupiti della sua presenza.